# Is it possible to refer a BitmapImage that's in memory via a string-based path?

Tags: c#

I am using an API that works with images and one of the methods expects a path to a file on the physical disk.

The problem I have is that I'm retrieving images through a WCF service so the image already exists in memory. I don't want to have to write the file to disk just to have this method re-open it and operate on it.

Is there any way I can refer to the file in memory via a string-based path?

Comment: I know this is also a problem when dealing with the DirectX API - may times I've had to write wav files to disk before playing them.

Comment: Ironically (perhaps?), this is a MS API that I'm dealing with as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.  Long answer, you can use a ram disk as a hack.  Accepting only a filename (and not alternatively a Stream), is a flaw in the API.

Comment: Definitely a flaw in the API. Very short sighted :(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could set up a [Ramdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk).